# Implementing shift click and click functionality on the same element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to implement an on click event in d3 but I also want to have the option to shift click on the same svg element to trigger a different functionality. If I click on the element, I want it to call me clicked() function, but if I shift click on the element, I want it to change it's fill style to "steelblue". I am trying to do:

```
.on("click", function(d){
      if (d3.event.shiftKey) {
          d3.select(this).style("fill", "steelblue");
      }
      clicked(d);
 })
```

but I just get "Uncaught TypeError: t.getAttribute is not a function" from d3 because my clicked() function is not being called or passed in parameters correctly I'm assuming.

If I do:

```
.on("click", clicked);
```

my clicked() function works perfectly, but I have no way of implementing the shift click functionality. Does anyone know a way to get both functionalities working? My clicked function is essentially a zooming function that takes in datum d by the way.

Comment: If it works without `d` but doesn't work with `d`, maybe look into that?

Comment: Please include your clicked function.

Answer (score 1):

> If I do `.on("click", clicked);`my clicked() function works perfectly, but I have no way of implementing the shift click functionality.

Why not? Of course you can. Just check for the shift inside the `clicked` function.

Here is a basic demo:

```js
var circles = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 50 + 100 * d
  })
  .style("fill", "darkgray")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("cursor", "pointer")
  .on("click", clicked);

function clicked() {
  if (d3.event.shiftKey) {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "steelblue");
  }
  console.log("This is the clicked function")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

For completeness, this is the problem of your first snippet: when you attach a listener using [selection.on](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_on),

> The specified listener will be evaluated for the element, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (nodes[i]).

However, in your case, you're passing just the datum to the `clicked` function:

```
clicked(d);
```

Therefore, the `clicked` function has the incorrect reference to `this`, which will be the [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). Check the snippet below:

```js
var circles = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 50 + 100 * d
  })
  .style("fill", "darkgray")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("cursor", "pointer")
  .on("click", function(d){
   clicked(d)
  });

function clicked(datum) {
  console.log("The datum is: " + datum);
  console.log("'this' is: " + this)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

A simple workaround is keeping the reference to `this`:

```js
var circles = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 50 + 100 * d
  })
  .style("fill", "darkgray")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("cursor", "pointer")
  .on("click", function(d) {
    var self = this;
    clicked(d, self)
  });

function clicked(datum, thisElement) {
  console.log("The datum is: " + datum);
  console.log("'this' is: " + thisElement)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Or using [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (as suggested by [@DavidKnipe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064808/david-knipe)):

```js
var circles = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 50 + 100 * d
  })
  .style("fill", "darkgray")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("cursor", "pointer")
  .on("click", function(d) {
    clicked.call(this, d);
  });

function clicked(datum) {
  console.log("The datum is: " + datum);
  console.log("'this' is: " + this)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: And if `clicked` is a function provided by someone else which you can't rewrite, you can call it with the correct `this` as follows: `clicked.call(this, d);`

Comment: @DavidKnipe yes, indeed. But a word of advice: there is a method in D3 also named `call`, which is not the same of the vanilla JS `call`. But, unless one uses `call` with a selection, it will work.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado great explanation